# I keep getting "No Persistence provider for EntityManager" when trying to run Vogella.de JPA tutorial

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I am trying to get the tutorial at http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html#simple to work. It has not been so simple. I know this is probably stupid simple for most people but I dont have any JPA experience or EJB experience. My end goal is to use JPA in a java desktop type app.

When I try to run the example I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named todos
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at de.vogella.eclipse.ide.main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

I do have /src/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>de.vogella.jpa.simple.model.Todo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:derby:/Users/james/Desktop/simpleDb;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

/jpa_example/src/de/vogella/jpa/simple/model/Todo.java

```
package de.vogella.jpa.simple.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Todo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String summary;
    private String description;

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Todo [summary=" + summary + ", description=" + description
                + "]";
    }

}
```

/jpa_example/src/de/vogella/eclipse/ide/main/Main.java

```
package de.vogella.eclipse.ide.main;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import de.vogella.jpa.simple.model.Todo;

public class Main {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "todos";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        // Read the existing entries and write to console
        Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Todo t");
        List<Todo> todoList = q.getResultList();
        for (Todo todo : todoList) {
            System.out.println(todo);
        }
        System.out.println("Size: " + todoList.size());

        // Create new todo
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setSummary("This is a test");
        todo.setDescription("This is a test");
        em.persist(todo);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
    }
}
```

I have been running in circles trying to get any basic JPA tutorial to work. I have no java database experience and I have not been developing web applications with java before so most of the lingo is over my head. By the way I am actually interested in using JPA with a javaSE desktop application, not a web application. I really wish I could just download an already working eclipse jpa project but I have yet to find one. I just find tutorials that after spending a couple hours trying to get them working I give up and move on to the next. Is there a better tutorial that has a downloadable project to get me started?

Comment: Are you missing the `eclipselink.jar` JAR in your lib folder/build path?

Comment: BalusC, Thats probably the problem. However for some reason ever since I installed the EclipseLink, and the other JPA/webtools stuff I cant use project explorer any more. When I open it there is just a stack trace in its place with "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find id: org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.EnhancedJavaRendering". I am still making a stab at fixing that myself. If a little more time goes by and I cant fix that I will probably make a post here. Just wondering, if I am using eclipse classic do I even need any other plugins to do non web development using JPA?

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the tip about @ Nickname. I didnt realize that worked on here. I will download java EE this weekend and try again when I have the free time.

Comment: @BalusC. Honestly I have moved on and no longer to EE development. I  can't really even remember any specifics about this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tag missing in your persistence.xml as the error message suggests. Add the following line before the `<class>`-tag with the provider implementation you use (the example shown uses OpenJPA implementation):

```
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
```

Comment: Not mandatory, and certainly not the one causing his error; if there is only one JPA implementation in the CLASSPATH then it will use that with the specified persistence-unit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was just trying to follow the tutorial. I came across the same problem. The problem is fixed by adding missing jar eclipselink.jar into class path.

Also if you are using Windows, which seems you are using it, you should update your path definition as the following.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
        value="jdbc:derby:C:\Users\james\Desktop\simpleDb;create=true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error and I solved it:

1. Check the correct position for the META-INF directory. 
   My META-INF was a 2nd source folder in the project root and not located in the source root.
   I fixed this by:

   a) saving the `persistence.xml` file.
   b) deleting the `META-INF` , because it is a separate source folder.
   c) opening the `.classpath` and remove the entry for `META-INF` as `src` 
   This can be done by: "Projet Explorer">"YourProject"> [right click] > Build Path > Configure Build Path .
    
   As an alternative, you can edit the hidden `.classpath` file in "YourProject"'s root 
   The Result should look like:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <classpath>
           <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
           <classpathentry kind="lib" path="jlib/derby.jar"/>
           <classpathentry kind="lib" path="jlib/eclipselink.jar"/>
           <classpathentry kind="lib" path="jlib/javax.persistence_2.1.1.v201509150925.jar"/>
           <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
           <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
       </classpath>
   ```

   I use a `/jlib` folder in "MyProject"s root, to host the projects jar-files, so it is easy to export the project with the jar-files, because this is a further possible reason for an error. 
   d) after the deletion, I created a folder into the `src` folder: "Project Explorer" > "Your Project" > at `src` [right click] > New > Other > General > Folder > name it: "META-INF" 
   e) copy the stored `persistence.xml` file into the new META-INF folder.
2. Check all your paths 
   Especially the path for the database, set in `persistence.xml`:

   ```
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
    value="jdbc:derby:**/home/yourHome**/DerbyDBBasics/ToDoDb;create=true" />
   ```

   **The original path from the sample is not your private path!**
   Try to create, read, and write a simple text file to ensure your program have access rights with your user account, otherwise use a path on which you have this rights, and change the value by assigning your path to the properties `value="jdbc:derby:`, followed by "`;create=true"`".